# Modifying Symfony 2 forms behavior

Tags: jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony 2.

The way my forms are working is like the following :

- Forms are submitted in Ajax (JQuery)
- If there are errors in my form, I receive an XML response with all error messages

```
    <errors>
    <error id="name">This field cannot be blank</error>
    <error id="email">This email address is not valid</error>
    <error id="birthday">Birthday cannot be in the future</error>
    </errors>
```

- If there is no error in my form, I receive an XML response with redirect URL

```
    <redirect url="/confirm"></redirect>
```

- **My question is** : how can I change "forever" the behavior of forms in Symfony 2 so that I could use a controller like the following :

```
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
    $member = new Member();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($member)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('birthday', 'date')
    ->getForm();

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
    // returns XML response with redirect URL
    }
    else {
    // returns XML response with error messages
    }
    }

    // returns HTML form
    }
```

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A form handler is how I do it as well. Validate the form in the formHandler and create your json or xml response in the controller depending on the response from the formHandler.

```
<?php
namespace Application\CrmBundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Application\CrmBundle\Entity\Note;
use Application\CrmBundle\Entity\NoteManager;

class NoteFormHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $noteManager;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, NoteManager $noteManager)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;  
        $this->noteManager = $noteManager;
    }

    public function process(Note $note = null)
    {
        if (null === $note) {
            $note = $this->noteManager->create();
        }

        $this->form->setData($note);

        if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                $this->onSuccess($note);

                return true;
            } else { 
                $response = array();
                foreach ($this->form->getChildren() as $field) {
                    $errors = $field->getErrors();
                    if ($errors) {
                        $response[$field->getName()] = strtr($errors[0]->getMessageTemplate(), $errors[0]->getMessageParameters());
                    }
                }

                return $response;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function onSuccess(Note $note)
    {
        $this->noteManager->update($note);
    }
}
```

This only returns 1 error message per field but it does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider encapsulating this logic in a "form handler" service, similar to what is done in FOSUserBundle:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler.php